# networking default gateway, default route

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking, subnet, netmask

in ipv4 cidr notation you can have an ip address like 10.10.20.0/24

it's expanded to

```
network  : 10.10.20.0
first ip : 10.10.20.1
last ip  : 10.10.20.254
broadcast: 10.10.20.255
netmask  : 255.255.255.0
```

That means I have a usable ip range from 10.10.20.1-.254 on this subnet.

would 10.10.20.0 be the default gateway for this subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default gw (if any) could be at any IP in that range. From first IP to last IP.

The network and broadcast address are reserved, and can not be used by any device.

In summary, we don't know what the gateway IP is, but we do know that it can not be 10.10.20.0 since that is network address.

Comment: who decides the default gateway for that ip address range? Can the default gateway change?

Comment: The network administrator that sets up the network, yes it can change, you can have multiple etc etc